# Subsetting SAS data set by earliest date for each subject

Tags: date, sas

I am attempting to retrieve a subset of a SAS data set based on the earliest instance of an event for each particular subject. 
Here is an example data set:

```
subject    date
001        12/22/2009
001        01/14/2016
001        03/20/2014
002        02/12/2007
002        01/23/2015
```

I just want the following:

```
subject    date
001        12/22/2009
002        02/12/2007
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use by-processing with `first.` :

```
/* sort into order */
proc sort data=have ;
  by subject date ;
run ;

/* Take 1st record per subject (i.e. earliest date) */
data want ;
  set have ;
  by subject ;
  if first.subject ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 3):

by proc sql you can as shown below

```
 proc sql;
 create table want as
 select * from have
 group by subject
 having date=min(date);
```

or you can use proc means

```
   proc means data=have  nway;
   class subject;
   var date;
  output out=want(keep =id date) min(date) =date;
  run;
```

Answer (score 2):

The PROC MEANS example from @Kiran would be my preferred method slightly modified to use the IDGROUP option on the OUTPUT statement.  It works essentially the same way as the "chosen solution" but requires no sorting.  I modified the date variable to iso8601 character format to show that IDGROUP also supports character variables.

```
data have;
   infile cards firstobs=2;
   input subject:$3. date:mmddyy.;
   dtc = put(date,yymmdd10.);
   random = ranuni(134);
   format date date9.;
   cards;
subject    date
001        03/20/2014
002        02/12/2007
001        01/14/2016
001        12/22/2009
002        01/23/2015
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary data=have nway;
   class subject;
   output out=want(drop=_type_) idgroup(min(dtc) obs out(date--random)=);
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```